# read and plot text file in matlab after making some transformations

Tags: file, matlab, text

i managed to make text files and separate in matlab like that:

0002 0004 0FCF 19B1 0713 0003

0002 0005 0FD9 19B3 0712 0003

0002 0006 0FD0 19B5 0713 0004

and the list goes on for many lines.

what I want to do now is to plot the last 4 columns. But first I want to make the values from hexadecimal to decimal and then use functions to take real values because the values are raw.

f.e: 0FCF and the rest of the column must be transformed to decimal from hexadecimal and then use the function: (decimalofthatvalue/4096)*3 to take the real value.
when this transformation is done I want to plot the whole column.

Any thoughts? I think that what I am trying to do is really simple but I am really new in matlab and I find it so hard!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "i managed to make text files and separate in matlab like that:"? Do you already have the data in the workspace? (then why writing it into textfiles?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse through all your columns with some for loops and use the hex2dec function to convert from hexidecimal to decimal.

ex:

> > hex2dec('0FCF')

ans =

```
    4047
```

EDIT**

it's not clear how you are handling your data. I assume that you have all the data in a text file and that you are importing it into MATLAB from that text file. I worked out a simple example for you. In my example, I use the data you gave in your question and saved it to a textfile called text.txt.

```
[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6] = textread('text.txt', ...
'%s %s %s %s %s %s', 3);
myData=horzcat(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);
myDecData=zeros(size(myData)); %allocate space for speed
RealValue=zeros(size(myData));
for i=1:size(myData,2)
    for j=1:size(myData,1)
        x=myData(j,i);
        myDecData(j,i)=hex2dec(x);
        RealValue(j,i)=(myDecData(j,i)/4096)*3;
    end
end
%now plot columns
figure,plot(RealValue(:,3)); %this plots third column
```

This may not be the best way to do it, but it's simple and gets the job done

Comment: I know that it can be done with for. but the thing is what exactly should i use?